# How to pass LPCSTR * from VB.Net or C# to use ObtainUserAgentString

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi

Here is my code and I get error input arguments

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1
    Private Declare Function ObtainUserAgentString Lib "urlmon.dll" (ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByRef pcszUAOut As String, ByRef cbSize As Integer) As Integer
    Sub Main()
        Dim c As String
        Dim ptr As IntPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(c)
        Dim useragent As String
        Dim size As Integer
        Dim result As Integer
        result = ObtainUserAgentString(0, useragent, size)

        'Try
        'result = ObtainUserAgentString(0, ptr, size)
        'Finally
        '    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr)
        '    'End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Shared/MS/Win32/UnsafeNativeMethodsOther.cs,f80d15b4396ab14d,references) reveals that the `ObtainUserAgentString` function is defined as:

c#

```cs
[DllImport(ExternDll.Urlmon, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
private static extern MS.Internal.Interop.HRESULT ObtainUserAgentString(int dwOption, StringBuilder userAgent, ref int length);
```

vb.net

```vb
<DllImport(ExternDll.Urlmon, ExactSpelling:=True, CharSet:=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi, BestFitMapping:=False, ThrowOnUnmappableChar:=True)> _
Private Shared Function ObtainUserAgentString(dwOption As Integer, userAgent As StringBuilder, ByRef length As Integer) As MS.Internal.Interop.HRESULT
End Function
```

So the answer to your question is [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).